# Displaying multiple plots in Matlab figures

Tags: matlab

I want to draw 2 figures and save them as `suva1.fig` and `suva2.fig` respectively. In the first figure there are 5 identical lines and in the second figure there are 4 identical lines. Following is the my codes. But I cant get the desired plots. Please indicate how to edit the code to get the desired results.

```
clear all
clc
x1=[1:1:50];
y1=[1:1:50];
x2=[1:2:100];
y2=[1:2:100];
for i=1:2
if (i==1)
    for j=1:5
h=figure
plot(x1,y1,'o')
hold on
    end
saveas(h, 'suva1','fig')
end
if (i==2)
    for j=1:4
h=figure
plot(x2,y2,'o')
    end
saveas(h, 'suva2','fig')
end
end
```

Comment: A. you don't need the i-loop and the `if` statments.(@Shai will tell you also to choose other variable for the loop...) B. You missed `hold on` in the second figure

Comment: C. You run over the first plot with the second one

Answer (score 1):

From your code, it doesn't look like you're trying to display multiple plots in a single figure.  Also, I'm not sure why you put the loop 
    for(j = 1:5)

To plot multiple lines on the same plot, use the hold on command:

```
h=figure
plot(x1, y1, 'o'); hold on;
plot(x2, y2, 'k');
hold off;
```

To use subplots:

```
h = figure;
subplot(2,1,1);
plot(x1,y1,'o'); hold on;
subplot(2,1,2);
plot(x2,y2,'k');
hold off;
```

To save 2 separate plots:

```
h = figure;
plot(x1,y1,'o');
saveas(h, 'suva1','fig');
close(h);
h2 = figure;
plot(x2,y2,'o');
saveas(h2, 'suva2','fig');
close(h2);
```